# Java Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Party Class. The idea is, a Party can only have 1 active `Contract` he initiated if he is type A. He can have multiple active `Contract` if he is type B.

Party1 - type A
Party2 - type B
Party3 - type A

Party1 can initiate Contract1 with Party2.
Party3 can initiate Contract2 with Party2.
Party2 can initiate Contract3 with Party1.
Party2 can initiate Contract4 with Party3.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTY")
public class Party {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "initiator", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Contract> contracts = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT")
public class Contract {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Party initiator;
    private Party confirmingParty;
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private boolean active;
    @Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_START_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime effectiveStartDate;
    @Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime effectiveEndDate;
}
```

Given the constraints above, I am not sure how to relate the Party in my Contract class. Should it be @ManyToMany ?

Contract Database expected (can be adjusted):

```
id | initiator | confirming_party | active | ...
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1         | 2                | Y      | ...
2  | 3         | 2                | Y      | ...
3  | 2         | 1                | Y      | ...
4  | 2         | 3                | Y      | ...
```

Comment: Does that mean a contract can only have two parties?

Comment: yes, a contract can only have two parties

Answer (score 0):

Based on the your database model for Contract, I can say that you need to have a ManyToOne relationship from Contract to Part like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "initiator")
private Party initiator;

@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "confirming_party")
private Party confirmingParty;
```

For the conditions you mentioned, you can use hibernate unique constraints but it should be conditional unique constraints. But I am not sure whether hibernate support it or not. I could not find.

If not, you need to check conditions before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you describe your question, there is a definitely **many-to-many** relationship between *Party* and *Contract*. Unless you use inheritance to declare two different types of *Party* class as

- PartyA (contracts as many-to-one) extends Party
- PartyB (contracts as many-to-many) extends Party

You will have to programmatically control the *one-to-many* and *many-to-many* relationships between party type and contracts.

Having said that, based on the following conditions

- A contract can have many parties (i.e. based on your comment its more than one hence, qualifies for many to many)
- A party can have more than one contract (i.e. based on Party type B, hence qualifies for many-to-many)

Hence, the best approach would be to create a *many-to-many* relationships table and then use either of the options

1. Use Hibernate's **JoinTable** annotations to connect **Party** with **Contract** using join columns in many-to-many table
2. Create another Java entity called *PartyLinkContract* which basically represents the *many-to-many* relationships (party_id, contract_id)

If you go with option one then whenever you make changes to the *Party* or *Contract* it will update the *many-to-many* table based on whether its *uni-directional* or *bi-directional* hence its very important not to use

```
CascadeType.ALL
```

Because, if you delete a *Party* then it will try to delete all its related *Contract* but, a *Contract* could be linked with more than one party hence, it gets tricky. The same applies from *Contract* end when deleting it it would cascade deletion of *Party* but, that *Party* could be linked with other contracts.

If you go with **Option 2** which is creating a linked entity java which represents the *many-to-many* relationship table, then you will have control over which entity relationship to persist and which one to update and which one to delete.

There are many tutorials that demonstrate how to implement *one-to-many*, *many-to-many* and *many-to-one* relationships in hibernate. You could google the following terms

1. Hibernate many-to-many relationships with annotations
2. Hibernate many-to-many relationship with join table annotation
3. Hibernate many-to-many relationships bi-directional

Instead of *CascadeType.ALL* you can use

```
cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE, ....}
```

To selectively use a specific type of *Cascade*.